# PaneSelector and options in a Module

Tags: programming, dynamic

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
  Module[{pr, ps, var, option},
   option = 1;
   var = 0;
   pr[] := Module[{}, var++; Print[var]];
   ps[] := Print["Test..."];

   PaneSelector[
    {1 ->
      Button["Defaults 1",
      option = 2,
      ImageSize -> 100],
     2 ->
      Button["Defaults 2",
      option = 1;
      pr[],
      ImageSize -> 100]},
     Dynamic[option]]
  ]
```

Note that pr[] is executed when the button "Defaults 2" is clicked.

**Question: I want to execute a function immediately after a Pane is selected in a PaneSelector construction. How should this be implemented?**

( Question translated to the context of the above snippet: how to execute either ps[] or pr[] immediately after setting option to 1 or 2?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work fine:

```
DynamicModule[{pr, ps, var = 0, option = 1},
 pr[] := (var++; Print[var]);
 ps[] := Print["Test... Option value is ", option];
 PaneSelector[{1 -> 
    Button["Defaults 1", option = 2, ImageSize -> 100], 
   2 -> Button["Defaults 2", option = 1;
     pr[], ImageSize -> 100]}, 
  Dynamic[Refresh[ps[]; option, TrackedSymbols :> {option}]]]]
```

It executes `ps[]` every time `option` changes. `Refresh` with `TrackedSymbols :> {option}` is used to prevent infinite recursion. Note: I also changed `Module` to `DynamicModule`.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used Refresh or TrackedSymbols before. Will try the code now.

Comment: It does work in a Module too. Is there a compelling reason to use DynamicModule ?

Comment: @ndroock1 There are several good reasons, documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html).